# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resources SAML Federation

Tags: spring, cors, saml, spring-saml, adfs2.0

i have this problem in production enviromment, it's happened because i'm trying to redirect user to federation to authenticate,
i'm using SAML authentication && IBM IHS

[console log of cors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jBwU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ADFS? Where is it in the picture?

ADFS does not handle CORS and there is no way to add this header.

You need to do this via a proxy.